# Plane Track Does Not Stay in Place

Tags: tracking

newbie here.
I'm trying to follow a tutorial but I am unable to make the tracker stay in one place. Once I play the video the tracker moves

- Need help to understand on how I can fix this.
- There are also times that I was able to place the tracker that it stayed in place but after a while it goes to the same state of not staying in place.

1st Image shows that tracker intended placing:

[image]

2nd image shows that the first two trackers already moved when the camera panning reached it.

[image]

3rd image shows that all trackers already moved from original place.

[image]

I got the video from pexels.com:
https://www.pexels.com/video/interior-design-of-a-living-room-4301617/

Comment: It would help if you included a link to the tutorial so that we can see what you've been told to do.

Comment: there are a lot of tutorials on tracking on youtube. try this one. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O67P0uzbQBk